# ssh-keygen - Should have an ip-address of the machine

Tags: ssh, centos7, ssh-keygen

i am trying to do ssh-keygen on my local machine(vm- centos7) but the pub key contains something like `.....3lAbPGNkyxuBV root@localhost.localdomain`

how can i get the ip-address of the machine in the pub key instead of root@localhost.localdomain.

Answer (score 0):

That text is just a comment, so you can just edit that part in any text editor ( vi / vim/ Nano / notepad) to anything you want. It's not used as part of the key.